# Can a non-root user kill an OS X "login item" launched with ServiceManagement Framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launchd

I am deciding between using a login item and launch agent.
In this respect I have few questions:

1. Is it possible for a non root user to quit a login item helper if it is launched with service management framework using SMLoginItemSetEnabled? Will the helper app be reloaded by launchD if it is killed by user or in some cases OS?
2. Why does apple not recommend presenting a UI with an app that can be executed via a LaunchAgent? Is there a problem if we present a minimal UI?
3. A login item as a helper application requires the main application to call SMLoginItemSetEnabled. This implies that the main app must be called at least once to enable the login item. This differentiates it from a launch agent which can be loaded as soon as the plist is installed on the system. Can we execute the helper login item irrespective if the user has opened the main app or not?

Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 2):

`LaunchAgents` that are configured using `SMJobBless` are intended to be non-gui services. They run without UI in the background, and don't run as the logged in user.

If you want a gui, you're going to have to use `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`, or manually install a user `LaunchAgent` via a `.plist` with the `"LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua"` property.

1. Helpers launched by `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` run as the current user, so they can be terminated by that user. The process will get relaunched if launchd detects that the agent went away because of a signal or due to an abnormal termination. If it terminates due to a clean termination it will *not* be restarted until the next login of the user (by clean termination we mean terminating with an exit code of 0, which will not happen if the program is killed e.g. via the activity monitor. If the helper has an option to quit, and that option causes it to exit with a 0 return code, then it will not be restarted, which would be considered good form by the application.
2. It's a stylistic thing - a user cannot disable the agent without interacting with the command line which would be considered poor standing. There is no issue displaying a UI from a `LaunchAgent`. As long as it's registered with the appropriate keys, it will be launched in the user's gui login context which means that it can be fully interactive. I have several applications which act like that - TunnelBlick, 1Password (this is via the LaunchAgent plist) and they only put up a menu bar item on startup.
3. If you're just shipping an application - e.g. via the app store, then there's no way to have anything automatically start without some interaction by the user - you have to launch the main app to get the helper to be enabled. The helper login item can be launched manually without ever launching the main application; but it won't have the 'launch at startup' magic enabled. If you can register a LaunchAgent plist, then you can get the launch at startup & starting it up immediately behaviour.

For uninstallation, however, `LaunchAgents` require the removal of the .plist, and interacting with launchd to disable it, items registered with the Service Mangement framework will naturally vanish once the app is dragged to the trash.

IMHO, (bit soapboxy, bit opinionated) If you're shipping a standard app with a helper, then rely on first launch before configuring such things as helper start on login; primarily because it keeps the user in control. Autoinstalling startup items is one of my pet peeves with windows applications (so many status bar items...).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a doubt though. W.r.t to your answer to question 1, I have made a main application that launches a background helper application "login item" using SMLoginItemSetEnabled. However if I kill this helper app from the activity monitor, I see the helper app is launched again by launchD. Is this a standard behavior as I thought too that a  user can quit the login item from the activity monitor or is it that I am doing something wrong? Also we can submit apps using LaunchAgents to appstore by utilizing Apple's SMJobLess utility.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` - if you look at the launchd state for the helper it says `"OnDemand" = true`, which means that it restarts if it's killed. `SMJobBless` is really for non-gui services. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Where can I look for the launchD state for the helper, i.e. does launchD also create a plist for login items with onDemand=true and stores it somewhere?

Comment: Does this imply that SMJobLess is only for LaunchDaemons? Can we use it to copy plist to /Library/LaunchAgents? If not how can we install the launchagent from the application without manually asking the user to copy the plist.

Comment: For helpers registered with `SMLoginItemSetEnabled `, I don't know where it puts the configuration, if it even puts them in a file somewhere. `SMJobBless` is only for LaunchDaemons. It won't copy to `LaunchAgents`, but does accept most of the keys listed in the `launchd.plist` documentation in the definition. It is, however a single binary; not an app bundle. If you're not sandboxed, you can put the plist anywhere yourself on first launch - if you need to put it somewhere privileged, then you can move it in place with a helper (using something like `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`)

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` state the login item will be "kept running", which seems to indicate it will be relaunched if it is killed:

> The Boolean enabled state of the helper application. This value is effective only for the currently logged in user. If true, the helper application will be started immediately (and upon subsequent logins) **and kept running**. If false, the helper application will no longer be kept running.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1501557-smloginitemsetenabled